# Can one use Royalty-Free images for free in an amateur computer game?

Tags: copyright

I'm trying to create a match-3 game and want to share it with my friends and my 15 Tumblr followers. I'm not going to make money at all, it's just about getting likes and studying a programming language. The goals of the levels are like "collect 20 chocolate cakes" and "make the golden ring touch the bottom of the field", and the tiles are 40x40 pixels. For now I have some scrawls of my own, but they look awful.

Do I have to pay for each image I want to use? May I use royalty-free stock drawings of cakes and rings? If no, do I get asked to delete the image *before* they make me pay a heavy fine?

And the second question is: is it safe to use Google/Samsung/Apple/WhatsApp emojis for this purpose?

I have compared my game to collages, and looks like it's only illegal to sell them. Or have I misunderstood everything, and one has to buy a photo to use it in a collage?

Comment: “Royalty free” doesn’t mean “free to use”. Can you clarify in what way the images have been licensed?

Comment: @Sneftel Actually, I am wondering _what_ images can be taken for free at all, wheather OS emojis are among them, and how dangerous it is to grab accidentally something protected.

P.S. I've just searched for "free vector images", opened one of the sites, looked for an object I needed, clicked one of the images, and it redirected to a site selling this image for $12. But what if searched for "free" and copied the image without any "research"?

Comment: OK, looks like there is an answer about using emojis: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16803/using-emoji-in-my-iphone-app

Comment: Well... *no* images, unless they explicitly give you permission. In most circumstances, copyright is automatic, and violating copyright exposes you to civil damages regardless of whether you knew the work was copyrighted. "Royalty free" describes a specific structure for a license you might obtain from the copyright holder, it's not something *about* an image (or other work).

Comment: @Sneftel That's sad, but thank you for the answer, anyway.

Comment: Concepts of royalty free and in the open domain are fundamentally not the same. You can allow a entity to use an IP royalty free and still 100% retain full copyright.

Comment: There are a lot of sites offering royalty-free images. Often they have limitations, which may include you not selling the work, but also might include you providing attribution in some way. Generally, if you use someone else's image, you are constrained by the specific conditions they place on it, if they're still in copyright. Otherwise, you could always use public domain material.